# Как перенести коллекцию из ejs в функцию javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Как перенести коллекцию из `ejs` в функцию `javascript`?

**Решение-1**

```
<a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#" onclick="setMessage3('<%=articles%>', '<%=article.id%>')"><%=article.title%></a>  
<script>               
    function setMessage3(articles, id) {
        <!--  Arbitrary code ...  --- --- -->
        console.log(id);
        console.log(thisArticles[id].content);
    }
</script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Решение-2**

```
<script>               
    function setMessage4(id) {                   
        let thisArticles = '<%=articles%>'; 
 
        console.log(thisArticles[id].content);
    }
</script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### Обновление-1

**Главная цель:** выполнить на странице `Master-Detail`.
Пользователь кликает по `<a>` в результате справа отображается текст статьи.

---

**Логика.**
Из контроллера получаем коллекцию.
В `index.ejs` строим левое меню с помощью:

```
<% articles.forEach((article, index) => { %>
    <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#"><%=article.title%></a>
```

Далее пользователь кликает по `<a>`.
Передаём `id` с помощью `<%=article.title%>` в функцию JS.

Далее с помощью JS:

- получить коллекцию `articles`;
- получить элемент коллекции `article = articles[i]`;
- получить свойство `article.content`;
- отобразить свойство `article.content` в элементе html страницы(Пример: отобразить в элементе div);

**index.ejs** (исходный... Потом планируется переделать)

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <!-- Кодировка веб-страницы -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Настройка viewport -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>...</title>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS (jsDelivr CDN) -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle JS (jsDelivr CDN) -->
    <!--
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</head>
<!-- <body> -->
    <body>
        <!-- class="container" -->
        <div class="container">
            
            <!-- div -->
            <div class="border border-success border-3 p-2 vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
                <!-- HEADER  --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- ---->
                <!-- <header class="py-4 text-center text-uppercase fs-4 bg-primary bg-gradient text-white">
                    Header
                    </header> -->
                    
                    <!-- ROW  --- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- --- --- -->
                    <div class="row py-3 flex-grow-1">
                        
                        <!-- LEFT MENU  --- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- -->
                        <div class="col-3 d-flex">
                            <aside class="bg-danger bg-gradient w-100 d-flex justify-content-left align-items-center text-dark fs-5">                                
                                <% if (articles.length > 0) { %>
                                    <ul>
                                        <% articles.forEach((article, index) => { %>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="hidden" class="articles" name="articles[]" value="<%= article.id %>">     
                                            <span>
                                                <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#"><%=article.title%></a>
                                            </span>                                
                                            <span>
                                                <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#"><%=article.owner%></a>
                                            </span>                                
                                            <span>
                                                <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#"><%=article.number%></a>
                                            </span>                                
                                            <span>
                                                <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#"><%=article.pos%></a>
                                            </span>
                                            
                                            <!-- <th scope="row"><%= article.id %></th> -->                                                                        
                                            <!-- <td><%= article.title%></td> -->
                                            <!-- <td><%= article.content %></td>
                                            <td><%= article.background %></td> -->
                                            <!-- <td><%= article.owner %></td> -->
                                            <!-- <td>@<%= article.number %></td> -->
                                            <!-- <td>@<%= article.pos %></td>
                                            <td>@<%= article.lang %></td> -->
                                        </li>
                                        <%})%>
                                    </ul>
                                <%}%>
                                </ul>
                            </aside>
                        </div>
                        <!-- PLACEHOLDER  --- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- -->
                        <div class="col-9 d-flex">
                            <main class="bg-light bg-gradient w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-dark fs-5 border border-success border-3">
                            Placeholder
                            </main>
                        </div>
                        <!-- RIGHTBAR  --- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- --- --- -- -->
                        <!-- <div class="col-3 d-flex">
                            <aside class="bg-danger bg-gradient w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-white fs-5">
                            Right Bar
                            </aside>
                        </div> -->
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- FOOTER -->
                    <!-- <footer class="py-4 bg-info bg-gradient text-center text-uppercase fs-4 text-white">
                    Footer
                    </footer> -->
                    
                </div>
                
            </div> <!-- .container -->
            
        </body>
        </html>
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE DATABASE socka;

--
-- Структура таблицы `articles`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articles`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` text,
  `background` text,
  `owner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pos` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `lang` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=275 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;


--
-- Структура таблицы `articles`
--
INSERT INTO `articles` (`id`, `title`, `content`, `background`, `owner`, `pos`, `lang`) VALUES
(1, 'Articles-1', 'Content--Articles-1', NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
(2, 'Articles-1-1', 'Content--Articles-1-1', NULL, 1, 0, 1),
(3, 'Articles-1-2', 'Content--Articles-1-2', NULL, 1, 0, 1),
(4, 'Articles-1-3', 'Content--Articles-1-3', NULL, 1, 0, 1),
(5, 'Articles-1-1-1', 'Content--Articles-1-1-1', NULL, 2, 0, 1),
(6, 'Articles-1-1-2', 'Content--Articles-1-1-2', NULL, 2, 0, 1),
(7, 'Articles-1-1-3', 'Content--Articles-1-1-3', NULL, 2, 0, 1),
(8, 'Articles-2', 'Content--Articles-2', NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
(9, 'Articles-3', 'Content--Articles-3', NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
(10, 'Articles-4', 'Content--Articles-4', NULL, NULL, 0, 1),
(11, 'Articles-5', 'Content--Articles-5', NULL, NULL, 0, 2);
```

Comment: В консоль что-то будет выводить `console.log(thisArticles);` ? есть уверенность что это массив, а не строка?

Comment: @MrFylypenko См. **Обновление-1**. `console.log(thisArticles);` это предварительное решение, чтобы убедится, что можно получить коллекцию из `ejs`. **1.** Я ответил на вопрос? **2.** Или такое(задача описанная в вопросе) не так делается?

Comment: Думал тут проблема с `js`, а оказывается с `ejs` , не работал с ним и документация скудная. Добавьте тег `ejs` в вопрос.  Из того, что я понял, в вопросе попытка отображения статьи при клике слева должна быть без перезагрузки страницы. Думаю такое поведение не для ejs, а для [spa](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Одностраничное_приложение). Как вариант можно сделать отдельный обработчик запросов и все ссылки <a> с id статьи отправлять на него.

Comment: @MrFylypenko А с помощью AJAX?

Comment: С помощью ajax можно запросить и отображать на странице, но я не знаю, какой фреймверк используется помимо `bootstrap`, чтоб можно было это проще сделать. Для spa это правильный вариант. С отдельным обработчиком нашел [пример, где отображать содержимое по id статьи, смотреть на /edit/:id](https://github.com/jorflores/ejs-blog-mongo2022/blob/master/routes/routeindex.js)

Comment: Появились мысли, как сделать вариант ближе к вопросу. Для каждой статьи создавать скрытый div, и при клике по <a> показывать соответствующее содержание. Сейчас попытаюсь набросать в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Можно рисовать список ссылок как и указано в вопросе. В функцию показа статьи формировать ид для показа содержимого.

```
<% articles.forEach((article, index) => { %>
    <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#" onclick="showArticle('article-content-<%=article.id%>')"> <%=article.title%></a>
```

Так же ниже в блоке вывода данных рисовать содержимое статьи, id должен совпадать из , но не показывать его `display: none`

```
<% articles.forEach((article, index) => { %>
    <div style="display: none" class="content" id="article-content-<%=article.id%>">
        <%=article.content%>
    </div>
```

А при клике по ссылке показывать нужную статью, пример на чистом js

```js
function showArticle(articleId) {
  for (let elementsByClassNameElement of document.getElementsByClassName('content')) {
    elementsByClassNameElement.style.display = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById(articleId).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container d-flex">
  <div class="col-3 d-flex">
    <div class="border border-success border-3 p-2 vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
      <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#" onclick="showArticle('article-content-1')">content 1</a>
      <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#" onclick="showArticle('article-content-2')">content 2</a>
      <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="#" onclick="showArticle('article-content-3')">content 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9 d-flex">
    <aside class="bg-danger bg-gradient w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-white fs-5">
      <div class="content" id="article-content-empty">
        Empty content
      </div>
      <div style="display: none" class="content" id="article-content-1">
        Content 1
      </div>
      <div style="display: none" class="content" id="article-content-2">
        Content 2
      </div>
      <div style="display: none" class="content" id="article-content-3">
        Content 3
      </div>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Недостаток данного решения: не желательно применять для задач с большими объёмами текста.... Я правильно понимаю? Или ничего страшного?

Comment: Да, правильно понимаете. На первом этапе этого будет достаточно, а когда столкнётесь с бОльшими объемами данных, то тогда переделать отображение по id статьи как указал в комментарии вопроса, или на ajax подгрузку. В этом ответе ориентировался на данные из вопроса.